# Multiline terminal outputs while debugigng Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, meteor, terminal

I build a mobile app with Meteor.js + Cordova and I have to run it on device (I use some plugins that are not implemented in emulators) - the problem is when I get an error / exception e.g. `Exception from Tracker afterFlush function` I've got only first line of this message and not actual error - it looks like this:

```
(android:http://meteor.local/packages/meteor.js:906) Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
```

And I don't see actual error message - I know that in browser there is a multiline message, but in terminal I don't have it - is there any way to achieve full error messages in terminal while debugging Cordova/Meteor.js app (I'm on OSX 10.10)?

Comment: Did u make your webview debugable?

Comment: Thanks! I've totally forgot about this chrome feature (I'm using firefox constantly and not used to work with chrome during development)